# Method for limiting an image to certain colors

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I've got certain 11 colors that I want to limit a normal RGB image to them, the method I'm using right now is finding the nearest color using the minimum Euclidean distance, the simplest method,
But since I'll be using a microprocessor to do so in the future, speed is important to me,
Are there other methods such as ANN or other machine learning or image processing techniques I can use to speed up the process?
Thanks in advance

P.S.: what is the name of this problem? So that I can search better

Comment: You already decided on those 11 colors and want to map it, or do you want to optimize those 11 colors (which ones)?

Comment: No actually I have them, certain colors @sascha

Comment: So it's a pure neighbor-search problem? What should ANN or ML do then?

Comment: I know I was just wondering If I could use other methods just to speed it up, rather than using the minimum distance for every pixel

Comment: Benchmark it. By the way, you can use the minimum squared distance (you don't need to take the square root first), since if a*a < b*b, it follows that a<b for positive, integral a,b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got your 11 colors, build some [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) (or similar data-structures; a keyword to search for would be *spatial data partitioning trees*) with those 11 vectors of size 3 (RGB) each.

Remark: those data-structures need you to define the metric in use.

Euclidean-distance / L2-norm sounds okay, but from an image-algorithm perspective, i recommend transforming everything to some [color-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) build for human-perception and then use L2 on that.

Then for every pixel of your image, you query the nearest-neighbor, the core method of these data-structures.

The possible speedup depends on details. As Mark said: benchmark it!

The keyword you are looking for is probably [Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). There are many alternatives, including approximations (probably not needed for your case).